# open() - Fortran runtime error: File '' does not exist when exe ran with Python / Bottle

Tags: python-2.7, fortran, bottle

I have a Fortran exe that is being moved on to an IaaS.  The Fortan exe runs fine when run from console (Windows), but when I call the exe from Bottle RESTserver (locally) the file paths do not work and the I get the following error:

```
At line 79 of file MainCalculator.f90 (unit = 61, file = '└')
Fortran runtime error: File '' does not exist
```

Here is my Python / Bottle code to execute the Fortran:

```
def model():
    curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    exe = "Calculator.exe"
    path = os.path.join(curr_dir, 'bin', 'fortan_model', 'Debug', exe)
    a = subprocess.Popen(path, shell=False)
    a.wait()
```

Here is the line of code that throws the error in Fortran:

```
open(UNIT=61, FILE=trim(adjustl(recipePath))//"Scenarios.txt")
```

where, `recipePath = '..\..\ourRecipes\OUR_recipes_082014\'` (defined in another .f90 file)

It seems the file path is being reported as an ASCII value (file = '└'), which does not happen when the exe is run from command line.  I thought it maybe the relative paths, but it gives the same error with absolute paths, but with `file = '≡f*☺└'`.

It also creates a file name `'   Scenarios.txt'` (with spaces in front).

EDIT:  The Fortran .exe reads an input txt file.  Each row is assigned to a variable.  This works as intended from the command line, but when executed from Bottle, it parses the input file as blank characters.  Do I need to grant Python permission to read the file and/or open the input file in memory?

Comment: Try to print the content of `recipePath` before the `open` statement. If it contains something strange, try to find out why. Be sure to enable all run-time checks and warnings. (`-fcheck=all`).

Comment: I am unable to print the Fortran write(*,*) statements in the Bottle console window, whereas I can print from the Bottle Python script.  The write(*,*) statements show when run command line, just not when executed through the Bottle script

Comment: Write it to a file then, or use a debugger, or whatever.

Comment: The path appears to be correct as held in the String variable.  The problems appears to an character encoding issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I solved this problem by decreasing the size of the output file name.